# Cannot install plotutils package

Tags: package-management, scientific-linux

I am on Scientific Linux, and have managed to install other packages in the past.
However, I cannot install plotutils (I believe I need the developer version).
I have been using the following code to install:

```
$ sudo yum install plotutils
```

to which I get the message:

```
This system is not registered with Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register
No package plotutils available
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have tried registering my system to subscription.rhsm.redhat.com via the subscription manager. However on entering my Red Hat account information I get the error: "User *myusername* is not able to register with any orgs."

I am not sure why this package won't install why others such as readline-devel will. Also, I am not sure if I have forgotten to do something which is preventing me from registering my system. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running Scientific Linux, or RedHat Linux?

Comment: Scientific Linux. As I understand, it is a derivative of Red Hat.

Comment: Centos does not use the RedHat subscription manager, so I'm curious why Scientific Linux would have that RedHat feature installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my available repos (I'm on RHEL 7 via AWS, I can share what repos I've got for those that care):

```
[root@plaidmin pam.d]# yum search readline-devel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
====================================================== N/S matched: readline-devel ======================================================
readline-devel.i686 : Files needed to develop programs which use the readline library
readline-devel.x86_64 : Files needed to develop programs which use the readline library
```

Whereas:

```
[root@plaidmin pam.d]# yum search plotutils
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Warning: No matches found for: plotutils
No matches found
```

Now I don't know what repos Scientific Linux has available, but you can always swing over to the site that hosts the source, pull the files down, and compile them yourself. It's a good habit to get into if ever you need to grab something that isn't so readily available, or if you can't muck with repos:

I googled `plotutils download` which brought this ftp up:

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/plotutils/

I confirmed that 2009 was the latest release on the first Google search's return for the site of this utility.

Right click the 2009 link->Copy Link Address.
In your terminal:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/plotutils/plotutils-2.6.tar.gz ##paste from your copy link address!
tar xzvf plotutils-2.6.tar.gz
cd plotutils
./configure; make; make install
```

Issue sudo and make sure you have permissions to the directories to which you're writing, if you are allowed to.

From the directory:

```
less README
less INSTALL
```

And follow the rest of the instructions. Should help you out.

Comment: I have followed these instructions, and I think it is now installed. Is there any way I can check that the full installation has been successful? I am still encountering a problem installing the software that required plotutils, but the error may be due to something else.